# Check IEnumerable<T> for items having duplicate properties

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

How to check if an IEnumerable has two or more items with the same property value ?

For example a class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

and then a collection of type `IEnumerable<Item>`

I need to return false if there are items with duplicate values in Prop1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this method will work.

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates<T1>(this IEnumerable<T1> source, Func<T1, T2> selector)
{
    var d = new HashSet<T2>();
    foreach(var t in source)
    {
        if(!d.Add(selector(t)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Or just `if (!d.Add(selector(t))) { return false; }` for the loop body.

Comment: Good call, that's a bit faster.

Comment: this is perfect! Just one small think. If collection contains a duplicate, true should be returned and when there is no duplicate, false should be returned :-)

Comment: the answer by @digEmAll also only traverses once

Comment: The method declaration should be ContainsDuplicates<T,T1> otherwise the code will not compile.

Answer (score 21):

You want to check only for Prop1 right ?

What about:

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = ...
var noDistinct = items.GroupBy(x => x.Prop1).All(x => x.Count() == 1);
// it returns true if all items have different Prop1, false otherwise
```

Comment: instead of `noDuplicated`, I would have used `notDistinct` as the variable name and use  and `Any` operator that checks if Count is bigger then one. by using `Any` you are not forcing yourself to itterate over the whole enumerable and exit the loop on the first case that matches the `Any` clause

Comment: @shirbr510, `All` doesn't force to iterate over the whole enumerable and exits the loop on the first case that **doesn't** match `All` clause. Unlike `Any`, `All` returns true for an empty enumerable, which seems better in this case. More on `All` and `Any` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027666

Comment: The Community Bot edit ([revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4597569/5)) is not an improvement. The `GroupBy` returns materialized groupings, for which the `Count()` is efficient (it doesn't force an enumeration). Replacing the `x.Count() == 1` with `!x.Skip(1).Any()` results in obscure code which is also less efficient and has different semantics (it is equivalent with `x.Count() <= 1`).

Answer (score 21):

A short, one-enumeration only solution would be:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    => !list.All(new HashSet<T>().Add);
```

which could be read as: *A list has **no** duplicates when* `All` *items can be* `Add`*-ed to a set.*

This is conceptually similar to Jake Pearsons solution; however, it leaves out the independant concept of projection; the OP's question would then be solved as:

```
items.Select(o => o.Prop1).ContainsDuplicates()
```

Comment: It seems the formatting got messed up in your last edit and the code block is now formatted as plain text. And more importanty this caused the `<T>`-tags to be removed, making the code invalid.

I would edit it myself, but since it is only whitespace, and I have nothing else to add, I'm not allowed to...

Comment: thanks, fixed! (weird mistake... I wonder what caused that; looks like some kind of auto-tab conversion)

Comment: @EamonNerbonne n1, also: `Func<IEnumerable<string>, bool> containsDuplicates = list => !list.All(new HashSet<string>().Add);`

Comment: Don't like the new in the predicate. I know it will be called only once, but I prefer using 2 lines to make it clear...

Comment: @Maxence: Technically, the `new` is not _in_ the predicate (as in, part of a delegate/lambda): it's used to _build_ the predicate. That's fine if you prefer two lines anyway, but I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool x = list.Distinct().SequenceEqual(list);
```

`x` is `true` if `list` has duplicates.

Comment: a nifty and readable solution but if I'm not wrong, it will cause multiple enumerations of `list`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Enumerable.Distinct(IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)?

Comment: This won't tell him if there are duplicate values, it will merely return the distinct values based on the comparer.

Comment: Just use `Count()` on both results to see if anything was removed... that was implied.

Comment: Some posters may be aware, some would not (and judging from the question, the OP may not be one of them).

Answer (score 3):

This could potentially be made for performant, but it's the only correct answer so far.

```
// Create an enumeration of the distinct values of Prop1
var propertyCollection = objectCollection.Select(o => o.Prop1).Distinct();

// If the property collection has the same number of entries as the object
// collection, then all properties are distinct. Otherwise there are some
// duplicates.
return propertyCollection.Count() == objectCollection.Count();
```

Comment: Ironically it is NOT a correct answer. Hint: Prop1 needs to be distinct, not Prop2.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the distinct values from the IEnumerable and then check the count against that of the full collection.

Example:

```
var distinctItemCount = myEnumerable.Select(m => m.Prop1).Distinct().Count();

if(distinctItemCount < myEnumerable.Count())
{
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `Distinct` checks for equality, and the objects that the OP is comparing are not necessarily equal.

Comment: Well then you'd chance `m => m` to `m => m.Prop1`

Comment: I think I updated my code just before you posted your comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(t => t).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key);
    }
}
```

Personally, I like the neatness of extension methods.
If your objects don't require a selector for determining equality, then this works nicely.

Answer (score -2):

We can remove duplicate entries by using `.Distinct()` in `ArrayList`.

## Example:

I have a `createdby` column in `testtable` with 5 duplicate entries. I have to get only one row

```
 ID   Createdby
 ===  ======== 
  1    Reddy
  2    Reddy
  3    Reddy
  4    Reddy
```

Considering the above table, I need to select only one "Reddy"

```
DataTable table=new DataTable("MyTable");//Actually I am getting this table data from database

DataColumn col=new DataColumn("Createdby");

var  childrows =  table.AsEnumerable().Select( row => row.Field<object>(col)).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: `DataTables`? `DataColumns`? Question is about knowing if there is a duplicate in an enumerable, not removing them.