# How to add a where clause to a field of a class with a one-many relationship with other class?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**Goal:**
Get all panels whose due date is <= today's date.

**Entity/db diagram**:
[image]
**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index(PanelViewModel panelViewModel) 
    {
        panelViewModel.Panels = _panelRepository.GetPanels()
                                  .Where(p => p.PanelApplicationForms.Count > 0
                                          && p.IsPublish
                                          && p.PanelApplicationForms != null)
                                  .OrderBy(t => t.Title);

        return View(panelViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public ActionResult Index(PanelViewModel panelViewModel) 
{
    var proj  = _panelRepository.GetPanels()
                              .Where(p => p.PanelApplicationForms.Count > 0
                                      && p.PanelApplicationForms
                                         .Any(f => f.PanelApplicationFormVersions
                                           .Any(v => v.DueDate <= today))
                                      && p.IsPublish
                                      && p.PanelApplicationForms != null)
                              .OrderBy(t => t.Title)
                              .Select(p => new { 
                                          Panel = p, 
                                          PanelApplicationForms = p.PanelApplicationForms
                                           .Where(f => f.PanelApplicationFormVersions
                                           .Any(v => v.DueDate <= today))
                                          })
                              .ToList();

    panelViewModel.Panels = proj.Select(p => p.Panel);

    return View(panelViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I know it is from the OP's code, but yeah...  `p.PanelApplicationForms.Count > 0` throws an exception in EF, it should be Any(). Likewise `p.PanelApplicationForms != null` throws an exception in EF (and is redundant anyway). Apart from that, this does not exclude Panels that _also_ have dates > today. But the OP is not specific whether this is a problem. Inituitively I would say that the condition should be `All(f => f.PanelApplicationFormVersions(All(v => v.DueDate <= today))`.

Comment: Difference between Any() and All() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027530/linq-not-any-vs-all-dont

Comment: The Eranga code worked for me, but there is one problem. It is showing the all the 'PanelApplicationForms' even if only one record of the 'PanelApplicationFormVersion' satisfy the DueDate condition.

How to not show the 'PanelApplicationForms' if the condition of DueDate is not satisfy?

Answer (score 0):

@Eranga thank you for the answer and comment above. I got it working doing the following,

Controller:

```
panelViewModel.Panels = _panelRepository.GetPanels()
                                 .Where(p => p.PanelApplicationForms.Count > 0
                                                    && p.PanelApplicationForms
                                                           .Any(f => f.IsPublish
                                                                     &&
                                                                     f.PanelApplicationFormVersions.OrderByDescending(v => v.VersionNumber).
                                                                         First().DueDate >= DateTime.Today
                                                                     && f.PanelApplicationFormVersions.Count > 0
                                                           )
                                                    && p.PanelApplicationForms != null)
                                          .OrderBy(t => t.Title);
```

View:

```
                       @foreach (var panelApplicationFormItem in panelItem.PanelApplicationForms.Where(panelApplicationFormItem => panelApplicationFormItem.IsPublish))
                        {
                            var panelApplicationFormVersion = panelApplicationFormItem.PanelApplicationFormVersions.OrderByDescending(v => v.VersionNumber).First();
                            if (panelApplicationFormVersion.DueDate >= DateTime.Today)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => panelApplicationFormItem.Title)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="span2">
                                        @if (panelApplicationFormItem.PanelApplicationFormVersions.Count > 0)
                                        {

                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => panelApplicationFormVersion.DueDate)
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="span2">
                                        @{
                                            //var isApplicationAlreadyExist = panelApplicationFormVersion.Id.IsApplicationAlreadyExist()
                                        }
                                        @if (panelApplicationFormVersion != null)
                                        {
                                            <a href="~/Application/Apply/@panelApplicationFormVersion.Id?versionNumber=@panelApplicationFormVersion.VersionNumber" class="btn">Apply</a>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <a href="#" class="btn">Sum</a>
                                        @*<p>No versions available to apply</p>*@
                                        }
                                    </td> 
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
```