# Is there an opposite of LINQ's All method?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently using

```
a_list.All(item => !(item.field_is_true == true))
```

which works well, but I'd like to know if there was a proper LINQ method to do the opposite of all.

Comment: Would it be called None?

Comment: @JonathanWood LINQ has no `None()` method.

Comment: I know, but it would be trivial to write one. Just return an empty set. My point was, isn't None the opposite of All?

Comment: Yes, it would be fairly simple to write `None` if you really wanted to, but `!set.Any()` accomplishes the same end as `None`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All() checks that a given Predicate returns true for all items. In terms of framework development, it wouldn't make any sense to write a seperate method that checks that a given Predicate returns false for all items, as it is so easy to "not" a predicate.
However, you can write your own extension method:

```
public static bool None<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Func<T, bool>` instead of the `Predicate<T>`

Answer (score 7):

The exact opposite of `All()` is essentially `None`, but since LINQ has no `None()` method, you can accomplish the same result through `!set.Any()`.

```
!a_list.Any(item => item.matches == true)
```

This will produce `true` if none of the items in a_list have a `matches` value that is true.

Another example:

```
names.All(item => item.StartsWith("R"))
```

is true if **all** of the items in `names` start with R (as you know already).

```
!names.Any(item => item.StartsWith("R"))
```

is true if **none** of the items in `names` start with R.

Based on your comment below, it sounds like you might just be looking for a way to accomplish the same result as your current code snippet, but in a different way.  This should provide the same result as your current code, but without the `!` in the predicate:

```
!a_list.Any(item => item.matches == true)
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
!a_list.Any(item => item.matches)
```

I'd imagine yours could be simplified as well, to this:

```
a_list.All(item => !item.matches)
```

There's rarely a good reason to explicitly compare a boolean value with `true` or `false`.

Comment: Assuming `.matches` is always `true`, wouldn't you only want the second `!`, without the first?

Comment: @TankorSmash I'm not sure. You haven't fully explained what you're trying to do.  I gave you the exact opposite of your example.  What are you trying to determine, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

you wrote:

```
a_list.All(item => !(item.field_is_true == true))
```

that is like doing:

```
a_list.All(item => item.flag== false)   // more readable to me...
        //return true if all of the items have a **flase** value on their flag
```

you can also use **.any()** to achieves the same result:

```
!a_list.Any(item => item.flag==true)
```

as for performence issues: **.any()**  vs **.all()**  -  **both would have identical performance**
(when linq to object is used) , find more here : [LINQ: Not Any vs All Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9027530/1219182)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than negate the All() condition, simply use the Any() with the same predicate and treat the returned boolean appropriately.

So, rather than:

```
bool conditionDoesntExist = a_list.All(item => !(item.field_is_true == true));
```

you can have

```
bool conditionDoesExist = a_list.Any(item => item.field_is_true == true)
```

Note the change in name of the flag. (Of course I'm overlooking semantic stuff like the original predicate could have been written as `item => item.field_is_true == false` or simply `item => !item.field_is_true` ).

If you want to keep the flag name the same then still use the Any() but negate it:

```
bool conditionDoesntExist = !a_list.Any(item => item.field_is_true == true);
```

Comment: there are not supposed to be performence differences when using **linq to object**. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9027666/1219182)

Answer (score 0):

**All**

```csharp
a_list.All(item => item.condition)
```

**Some**

```csharp
a_list.Any(item => item.condition)
```

**Not all**

```csharp
!a_list.All(item => item.condition)
```

or:

```csharp
a_list.Any(item => !(item.condition))
```

**None**

```csharp
!a_list.Any(item => item.condition)
```

or

```csharp
a_list.All(item => !(item.condition))
```