# How to check if all that is equal to A has property B to true?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class Person with two properties, genre and IsDead. I want to know if all men are death or not, in a list.

I am using this way:

```
if(myList.Where(x=> x.Genre == "MALE").All(x=> x.IsDeath == true));
```

But I don't know if there are other better option, instead of using a where and set all the properties in the All, Any... function.

Thanks.

Comment: Use x.IsDeath == true with && x.Genre == "MALE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do.

```
if(!myList.Any(x => x.Genre == "MALE" && !x.IsDeath))
```

Comment: OP wants _to know if all men are death_ Your solution will return true if any man is dead

Comment: Just add ! before myList.Any(x => x.Genre == "MALE" && !x.IsDeath)

Comment: @S.Petrosov - this is very "bad" and unreadable solution. Just use `All` method

Comment: I agree with @Fabio.  Using `!Any` will force it to iterate through the entire sequence whereas using `All`, it can quit iterating as soon as if finds a Male who is not dead.  Also `All` is easier to read.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I agree that `!Any` is confusing to read. But I don't think `Any` will force it to iterate through the entire sequence. Do you have any reference to this? Because according to this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027530/linq-not-any-vs-all-dont) both are same.

Comment: `All` is implemented with a not operator before the predicate, but I think you're right.  They both might short circuit under certain conditions now that I look at it closer.