# LinQ Item Present Validation

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

Currently I do this to validate if an item is present in the list

```
var wifiSSID = userLocation.LocationWiFiSSIDs.Where(x => x.WiFiSSID == attendanceDto.WiFiSSID).FirstOrDefault();
if (IsWiFiSSIDEnabled && wifiSSID == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ErrorMessages.InvalidWiFiSSID);
}
```

Can I write this in better way? With Any or Contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `wifiSSID` is only used for validation in your code, then you can use `Any()` as follows :

```
if (IsWiFiSSIDEnabled && !userLocation.LocationWiFiSSIDs.Any(x => x.WiFiSSID == attendanceDto.WiFiSSID)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ErrorMessages.InvalidWiFiSSID);
}
```

This way `userLocation` will be checked only if `IsWiFiSSIDEnabled` is `true`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use Any instead of All?

Comment: Is there any difference between Any() and All()?

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar Not much besides readability (which also varies from person to person, considering one's familiarity of a method over the other, for example. I'm not against dotNet's comment here btw) : [LINQ: Not Any vs All Don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027530/linq-not-any-vs-all-dont)

Comment: Thanks a lot @har07 :)

Answer (score 2):

Use all

```
if (IsWiFiSSIDEnabled && userLocation.LocationWiFiSSIDs.All(x => x.WiFiSSID != attendanceDto.WiFiSSID)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ErrorMessages.InvalidWiFiSSID);
}
```